# Save draft after page reload without registration via js or php

Tags: javascript, php, database

In my site, user can write a text. I want to make that, when the user reloads the page, the draft will appear. Without any registration.

I think, using ip as id is bad idea, because it can be library wifi network, for example, and as far as I understand, all connected devices would have the same ip.

What is the best way to unify client for that purposes?

Comment: Cookie, or session.

Comment: ... or localstorage

Comment: You can set cookie when client come on page, and save this cookie on database with text. Session is not good idea because session expire when user close browser.

Comment: @Argee, seems very useful. Localstorage is unique for each cite? I mean, if I set key “dog”, can another cite reset it?

Comment: @Artur yes, localstorage stores the data in the browser of the user... so as long as he uses the same browser he'll have access to the stored data. From my knowledge i think it should even work with multiple tabs, but i'm not 100% sure with that ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should use cookies if you want it to be saved for a long time

PHP:

```
setcookie('text_cookie', 'My text', time() + 3600);//To save for an hour
echo $_COOKIE['text_cookie'];//To show
```

Comment: Can it be saved, say, for a week using cookies?

Comment: Yes, you have got to specify the validity of your cookie as the 3rd argument:

The time() method returns the current timestamp, to which you can add the amount of seconds contained in a week: 3600 * 24 * 7 (and I would consider writing it as this calculus to be easily understandable!)

Comment: Can I access cookies via js?

Comment: Short answer: yes

Long answer: Your favourite search engine will provide

Answer (score 0):

use javascript keyevent and localstorage